# Modify a JSON using Python not working

Tags: python, json

I have json data like this:

```
[
{
    "select": false, 
    "children": [
        {
            "title": "NPS", 
            "key": "", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "Telstra", 
                    "key": "", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "Overall", 
                            "key": "", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "title": "NPS Score", 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-NPSScore", 
                                    "children": [], 
                                    "select": false
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "title": "% Promoters", 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-Promoters", 
                                    "children": [], 
                                    "select": false
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "title": "% Passives", 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-Passives", 
                                    "children": [], 
                                    "select": false
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "title": "% Detractors", 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-Detractors", 
                                    "children": [], 
                                    "select": false
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "title": "% Reactors", 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-Reactors", 
                                    "children": [], 
                                    "select": false
                                }
                            ], 
                            "select": false
                        }
                    ], 
                    "select": false
                }
            ], 
            "select": false
        }, 
        {
            "title": "NPS 2nd", 
            "key": "", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "Telstra 2nd", 
                    "key": "", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "Overall 2nd", 
                            "key": "", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "title": "%XYZ", 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-XYZ", 
                                    "children": [], 
                                    "select": false
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "title": "%ABC", 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-ABC", 
                                    "children": [], 
                                    "select": false
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "title": "%UV", 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-UV", 
                                    "children": [], 
                                    "select": false
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "title": "%MN", 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-MN", 
                                    "children": [], 
                                    "select": false
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "select": false, 
                                    "key": "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-JKL", 
                                    "title": "%JKL"
                                }
                            ], 
                            "select": false
                        }
                    ], 
                    "select": false
                }
            ], 
            "select": false
        }
    ], 
    "key": "", 
    "title": "Central Question"
 }
]
```

And I have a  lists of key values like:

```
mylist = ["NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-JKL", "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-MN", "NPS_Telstra_NA_NA_NPS-CVA-NPSScore"]
```

I want to modify the JSON `"select" key` from `False` to `True` only for those `key` values in the list.

I am not finding any way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to recurse through the structure; anything with a `children` key you recurse over, anything with a `key` key in your list you can alter:

```
def set_selects(data, keys):
    for item in data:
        if 'children' in item:
            set_selects(item['children'], keys)
        if item.get('key') in keys:
            item['select'] = True
```

This alters the structure in-place. It'll be more performant if you turn your list into a set:

```
data = json.loads(your_json_string)
set_selects(data, set(mylist))
```

Comment: So in as `data` i can pass the whole `json data` right ?

Comment: @DibyenduDutta: You pass in the *decoded* JSON data object, yes.

Comment: that was a perfect solution , you make the coding look so simple . Impressive :)